# What is the all_proxy environment variable used for?

Tags: proxy, environment-variables

When I type

```
set | grep -i proxy
```

I see all environmental variables which refers to proxy settings. I understand the meaning of **http_proxy** and **ftp_proxy** but what is **all_proxy** used for and where can I change it ?

It has been added to my environment variables when I used gnome-network-properties application. Why **socks** is specified there as a protocol?

```
all_proxy=socks://my_proxy:port/
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a post in a mailing list which says:

> We already export http,ftp,https proxy environment variables. Some environments,
>   GNOME for instance, place the socks proxy in ALL_PROXY and all_proxy. Export it
>   as well.

Here is the post http://lists.o-hand.com/poky/2431.html

So it's for the SOCKS proxy in gnome.

Comment: For those who (as me) were not familiar with socks protocol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS